# Multiple Editing of the same file

Tags: python, file, watch

What would I have to do to allow multiple programs/users to read/write to the same file ?

**Use Case**

I have a CSV file and I want to enable multiple users to edit it in more or less in real time. I want to be able to write and read the small changes in the file but I also want to be able to refresh the data, loaded in my program, in the event that the entire file is replaced by some careless soul.

**Background**

I have seen that certain programs will refresh a file if the time stamp is changed or the file is overwritten by another program/user. (I've used this myself when editing a file in two different editors leveraging their different features).

**Home Work**

I would imagine this requires my application to duplicate the original file when it is initially opened. In this way any updates to the original can be diff'd against the copy to get the modifications to the current data.  Then when the temporary file is updated the primary file can be re-written. Each user/program could then reload the updated files them selves. Is this a sensible way/Best practice or are there better means to an ends here.

Alternatively one could Cache the file from what I understand.

Is it better to block/lock the file ? Must I be wary of race conditions ?

**Environment**

I plan to do this in Python. I would also like this to be platform independent e.g. linux, windows and mac (expensive linux).

**Related**

It seems these are related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292940/writing-to-same-file-at-the-very-same-time), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566930/can-i-allow-multiple-programs-to-read-from-the-same-file-at-the-same-time) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757023/windows-open-the-same-file-simultaneously).

Comment: Why a csv file?  Seems you want a database.

Comment: Ah, I think that a database is the way to go here...

Comment: If a database is no good, have you considered using a pre-existing [collaborative real-time editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_real-time_editor), or concurrent [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system? It'd be much simpler than writing something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If the intensity of the edits is low, you can pull it of with csv file, but by locking the entire file to avoid users overwriting each other's edits. If the file cannot be locked until the edit is applied, you will be better by using DB, where specific records will be locked instead of the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

When a user opens the file you actually serve a copy of it file_userid-1.csv and let him edit that one to avoid users overwriting their work. When the user saves you overwrite the original one. In between you keep a hook to see if the original one was modified while current user also modified his. If the original file was modified you to a diff or something I don't know.

I think what you need is a tiny replica of how svn or git works.